# How can set format datetime [PHPExcel]

Tags: php, excel, datetime, phpexcel

set format datetime with php
and output excel

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Bangkok');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('S1', 'Show DateTime');
$dateValue = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel( strtotime('23-Apr-1989 17:05:50') );
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('S2', $dateValue);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('S2')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDDSLASH);
```

but output 
[image]

How can show data on Excel **23/04/1989 17:05:50** and excel type **Date**

Comment: But 1989 *is* >1900 and 1904 ...

Comment: Ah, apologies, I misread the date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You currently use the predefined constant `PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDDSLASH` for your number format.

If you replace that by your desired format, everything should be ok: `'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss'`

Also see the documentation for `setFormatCode()`: http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/ouardisoft/PHPExcel/class-PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat.html#_setFormatCode

Comment: data is correct, but excel type is Custom
If possible, I want to format Date in Excel

Comment: Unless you use one of MS Excel's predefined date formats, then it will be a custom format.... this should not be critical to any spreadsheet

Comment: @KwangKung: The answer is about changing the *format* of a cell, not its *data*. Have you tried it? Doesn't it exactly do what you want?